# tkinter GUI don't show up

Tags: python, tkinter, ssh

I am new to tkinter and i made my first GUI.
When i run my python script over SSH using Putty my script keeps on running while the GUI don't show up.
I have been trying and searching multiple things but nothing really worked.

GUI.py

```
from Tkinter import *

# Esempio di GUI

def main():
    w1=Tk()
    w1.title("Finestra 1")
    # Width, height in pixels
    f1=Frame(w1, height=50, width=50)
    f1.pack()
    w1.mainloop()

main()
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you ssh into another server? How can you expect a GUI to work?

Comment: Have you done any research about raspberrypi and tkinter? This is a really common failure.

Comment: [Do some research](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/99699)

Comment: Not another server. i SSH to my RPI from my laptop over ethernet.

Comment: when you run code on server then it displays it on monitor directly connected to this server, not on your local monitor.

Comment: Do you notice the DISPLAY error that comes up first?

Comment: if you use `Putty` then you probably use `Windows` but as I know `DISPLAY` works only on `Linux` - and you would have to run X-Windows on Windows. BTW when you connect from Linux to Linux using `ssh` then you can use `ssh -X ...` to redirect GUI (Linux X-Windows) from server to local computer.

Comment: if you use Windows then it can be simpler to use [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) to display desktop from Linux/RPi system - but it may need to install `VNC server` on `RPi`. And `RPi` has to run `XWindows` (graphic environment)

Comment: In Windows, you can use [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/download.html) which is a SSH client with X-Server.

Answer (score 0):

GUI do not work with raspberry and stuff